# Getting Exception while scrolling the table view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have table view with customize cell . I have 100 images on table view . When i run the application all images are get loaded on the table view .I can also scroll from top to bottom till 100th element. But while scrolling from bottom to to got the following exception at the somewhere at the middle at the fixed element :

```
     *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </Users/bc/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/B5090983-ACC0-4428-9741-255B7D72F674/ImageCaching.app> (loaded)' with name 'CustomCell''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x159b022 0x172ccd6 0x1543a48 0x15439b9 0x2fd638 0x2feeb7 0x33b7 0x176c54 0x1773ce 0x162c04 0x1716f1 0x11ad42 0x159ce42 0x1f53679 0x1f5d579 0x1ee24f7 0x1ee43f6 0x1f7f1ce 0x1f7f003 0x156f936 0x156f3d7 0x14d2790 0x14d1d84 0x14d1c9b 0x14847d8 0x148488a 0xdc626 0x298d 0x28f5)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

i have following code for table view:

```
   NSArray *objects=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
    NSLog(@"count =%d" ,[objects count]);
    CustomCell *cell=[objects objectAtIndex:0];
    Resource *r=[setUpArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
       cell.cellImage.image=[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[library getResource:r.key]];
```

I am loading nib name of customize cell accurately.Please give me some solution.

Comment: Do you have a nib named `CustomCell` ? Or maybe you were trying out a tutorial but changed name of your nib ?

Comment: "I am loading nib name of customize cell accurately" - well obviously, you don't. ;) Please show some code on how you create the cells or it won't be possible for anyone to help you.

Comment: The fixed element? It sounds like you have multiple types of cells and you're loading the wrong kind. Post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code and explain what you mean more specifically.

Comment: I think you have use high sized image
So memory issue might be possible.

Comment: Please post the full code you wrote in your program and other tableView methods

Comment: my table view should not load if i give wrong nib name. It loads and i can scroll to bottom.